# Custom DataGridViewColumn to restrict user input to numeric

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, numbers

I am trying to create a custom DataGridViewColumn with a custom DataGridViewTextBoxCell that would only accept numbers. All of the solutions I have found involve adding an event handler to the EditingControlShowing of the actual specific DataGridView. However, I want to create a custom DataGridViewColumn that, when added to any DataGridView, would automatically restrict user input.

Is there any way this could be done?

```
Public Class datagridviewNumberColumn
Inherits DataGridViewColumn

Public Sub New()
    MyBase.New(New datagridviewNumberCell())
End Sub

Public Overrides Property CellTemplate() As DataGridViewCell
    Get
        Return MyBase.CellTemplate
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As DataGridViewCell)


        If (value IsNot Nothing) AndAlso _
            Not value.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(GetType(datagridviewNumberCell)) _
            Then
            Throw New InvalidCastException("Must be a datagridviewNumberCell")
        End If
        MyBase.CellTemplate = value

    End Set
End Property

End Class

Public Class datagridviewNumberCell
Inherits DataGridViewTextBoxCell

Protected Overrides Sub OnKeyPress(e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs, rowIndex As Integer)
    MyBase.OnKeyPress(e, rowIndex)

    If Not IsNumeric(e.KeyChar) Then e.Handled = True

End Sub

End Class
```

My attempt is above but does not work. The OnKeyPress event is never fired. Am I missing something?

Comment: Defining the data type of a column of the associated `DataSource` is straightforward. There are different ways to restrict user inputs. Can you please show us what you have tried?

Comment: `Is there any way this could be done?`  Yes.

Comment: I have added what I have already tired

Comment: As said, there are different alternatives. You can use for example an event like `CellValidating`, precisely meant for this kind of actions. On the other hand, you might prefer to use other less aggressive approaches, like rather than checking each single inputted value, checking the whole string once it is submited, for example, `CellValueChange` (i.e., for "12345678" you just do one check rather than 8 ones; also situations like "1e10" might be problematic). Additionally you might play around with the types of the associated `DataSource`...

Comment: ... that is, if you define a given column of the DataSource as `Integer`, it would trigger an error in any other situation (and you might catch this error by relying on other events). In summary: there are many alternatives. `DataGridView` is a control with lots of functionalities which allows a very high flexibility. My advice: do some tests (there are more events/alternatives than what I have mentioned here), note the pro/cons of each approach down and make your decision accordingly.

Comment: I'm still trying to go with my solution because I want to be able to easily add a datagridviewcolumn within the designer without any extra steps. However, the OnKeyPress event is never fired. Am I missing something?

Comment: Where is the "Handles" in "Protected Overrides Sub OnKeyPress(e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs, rowIndex As Integer)
    MyBase.OnKeyPress(e, rowIndex)" ??  Maybe that's why it's not firing?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just want to restrict the user input in the datagridview to be integers, yes?
You should be able to do that with the column's ValueType property:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.valuetype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

For example:

```
            col.ValueType = GetType(Integer)
```

Just set that when you create and fill the datagridview.